# unable to loop hive sql queries in spark.sql

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I am facing challenges with below code to loop hive sql queries in spark.sql.

```
    def missing_pks(query: String) = {
          //println(f"spark.sql( $query )")
            spark.sql(query)
    }
var hql_query_list_df=spark.sql("select distinct hql_qry  from table where msr_nm='orders' and rgn_src='europe'")
var hql= hql_query_list_df.select('hql_qry).as[String].collect()
var hql_f=hql_query_list_df.map( "\"" + _ + "\"" )
hql_f.foreach(missing_pks)
```

here I am calling hive sql statements from table and load them as list then try to execute, unfortunately its not working. not sure what missing in my code. Interesting part is if the list was created manually with in spark shell code is working perfectly. It would be great if someone help me here.

Comment: Hive standard SQL authorization is enabled (doas=false)?

Comment: not sure how do I check that option?